# Translation of "lovableness / amiableness"

Tags: перевод

How to translate ***lovableness / amiableness*** into Russian?

I couldn't find anything. The question **is not** about ***courteousness*** (***любезность***).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would translate **"lovableness"** as **"привлекательность"**, which can be about both physical apperance and personality.

The definition of "привлекательность" is:
Способность нравиться, привлекать чьё-либо расположение или приязнь.

The definition of "lovableness" is:
Having characteristics that attract love or affection.

I would translate **"amiableness"** as **"приятность в общении"** or **"приветливость"**.

The definition of "приветливость" is:
От прилагательного "приветливый", проявляющий радушие, благожелательность

The definition of "amiableness" is:
(Comes from the adjective "amiable")
1. Friendly and agreeable in disposition; good-natured and likable.
2. Cordial; sociable; congenial.

Comment: Perhaps also обоятельность

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary I use knows nothing about both words, so I would translate "lovable" as "привлекательный" and make a noun from it. So it will be "привлекательность"
Same with "amiableness" -> "amiable" -> "благожелательный" -> "благожелательность"

Note that you can trace a chain like this for "courteousness" (-> "courteous" -> "любезный" -> "любезность")

It might not work with some words, but in main such method actually works.